# Combinaison de deux participes présents

Tags: participe-présent

Si on veut traduire une phrase comme

> Finding himself thinking of her, he continued to walk towards the bridge,

peut-on combiner les deux participes présents comme ça:

> En se voyant pensant à elle, il continuait de marcher vers le pont

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce n'est jamais une bonne idée de traduire mot à mot. Même s'il est possible de juxtaposer deux participes présents, le résultat n est pas toujours très heureux.

En ce qui concerne votre exemple, j'aurais dit:

"Conscient de penser à elle, il poursuivit sa route vers le pont".

Comment: Ou encore, en gardant un participe présent : "Rélaisant qu'il pensait à elle, il continua vers le pont".

Comment: et avec la correction de la coquille : "Réalisant qu'il pensait à elle, il continua vers le pont"

Comment: Merci ! Donc c'est toujours mieux de trouver un libellé qui évite de juxtaposer deux participes présents dans un tel cas ? Ou peut-on construire une exception ?

Comment: @tok3rat0r cela rend la phrase compliquée et peu élégante (imho) de juxtaposer deux participes présents

Comment: @tok3rat0r Je dirais que l'élégancedépend de la phrase... ton exemple  "S"imaginant plongeant dans la piscine, il eu un sourire satisfait", me paraît par exemple assez sympa. Je pense que c'est la traduction de ton exemple qui est plus malheureuse, ce qui explique les traductions plus élégantes.

Comment: Le premier pourrait être un participe présent et le second une formule avec *en train de* : *se réalisant en train de penser à elle*.